# merge fields in document

Tags: mongodb

Im currently trying to combine 2 fields together. like one column has "apple" and another has "red".

How would you combine 2 fields together and search by that specific pairing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using `$or` operator:

```
db.cityinfo.find({
  pop: { $gte: 6000, $lte:11000},
  $or: [
    { city: "SAN JOSE", state: "CA" },
    { city: "NEW YORK", state: "NY" },
    { city: "WASHINGTON", state: "DC" }
  ]
},{"_id":1})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/